# Rendering multiple forms with individual submit buttons but only form variables of first instance is being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I don't know what more to say apart from the title. In the rails view im looping through a div to render multiple employee profiles and along with edit button which toggles the profile to and edit form with fills the input field values from what was displayed. But on clicking "Save", only the first instance that is rendered, those form fields are being sent as parameters. Nothing happens when I click on "Save" on the other profiles. Even though the fields and forms are being rendered for all employees.

```
<div class="container team-inner">
        <%cleaners.each do |cleaner| %>
            <div id="employee-div" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 team-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <div class="img-container">
                                <%= image_tag('asset_emp2.png', class: '') %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 team-details">
                            <div class="toggle-field">
                                <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>First Name:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p><%=cleaner["first_name"]%></p>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="emp-id" value=<%=cleaner["id"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>Last Name:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p><%=cleaner["last_name"]%></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>Employee ID:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p><%=cleaner["employee_id"]%></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>Date of Join:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p><%=cleaner["date_of_join"]%></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>E-mail ID: </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p><%=cleaner["email"]%></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>Phone Number:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p><%=cleaner["phone_number"]%></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="row grid">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                        <p>Number of jobs done:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                        <p></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                            <form name="empEditForm"  class="toggle-field" style="display: none;" >

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">First Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="emp-edit-first-name" id="emp-edit-first-name" 
                                        class="form-control" value=<%=cleaner["first_name"]%>>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="emp-id" value=<%=cleaner["id"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Last Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="emp-edit-last-name" id="emp-edit-last-name" class="form-control" value=<%=cleaner["last_name"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Employee ID:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="emp-edit-employee-id" id="emp-edit-employee-id" class="form-control" value=<%=cleaner["employee_id"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Date of Join:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="emp-edit-date-of-join" id="emp-edit-date-of-join" class="form-control" value=<%=cleaner["date_of_join"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Email ID: </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="emp-edit-email" id="emp-edit-first_name" class="form-control" value=<%=cleaner["email"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Phone Number: </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text"  name="emp-edit-phone-number" id="emp-edit-phone-number" class="form-control" value=<%=cleaner["phone_number"]%>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                           <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Number of jobs done:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="43">
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->


                            </form>
                       <!-- <div class="row grid">
                                <div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
                                    <p>Rating:</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
                                    <p>Rating: <span>4.8</span></p>
                                    <p class="rating"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star rate"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star rate"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star rate"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star rate"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 edit-link">
                            <a href="#" class="btn save toggle-field toggle-btn">Edit</a>
                            <a href="#" id="save-btn" style="display:none;" class="btn save toggle-field" >Save</a>
                            <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="btn cancel toggle-field toggle-btn">CANCEL</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <%end%>
```

And this is the script Im calling on the save button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save-btn").click(function(){
       var token = localStorage.getItem("contractor_token").split(";");
       var first_name = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-edit-first-name"].value;
       var last_name = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-edit-last-name"].value;
       var emp_id = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-edit-employee-id"].value;
       var date_of_join = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-edit-date-of-join"].value;
       var phone_number = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-edit-phone-number"].value;
       var email = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-edit-email"].value
       var id = document.forms["empEditForm"]["emp-id"].value

       var jquery_selector = $('#emp-edit-email').val();
       console.log("jquery_selector value shows undefined below");
       console.log(jquery_selector);

        data["id"] = id;
        data["email"] = email;
        data["first_name"] = first_name; 
        data["last_name"] = last_name;
        data["phone_number"] = phone_number;
        data["employee_id"] = emp_id;
        data["date_of_join"] = date_of_join;
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({url: base_url + api_version + "/contractors/contractor_edit_employee",
                      type: "POST",
                      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":"bearer "+token[0]},
                      data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function(result){
                  //console.log(result);
                  location.reload();
          }
        });
    });
 });
```

UPDATE: Fixed this issue setting the `name` field for the form as the cleaner id itself in the loop.

```
<form  class="toggle-field" style="display: none;" name=<%=cleaner['id']%> >
```

Then I send the cleaner id as a function parameter on clicking on Save button.

```
<a href="#" style="display:none;" class="btn save toggle-field" onclick="return contractorEditEmployee('<%=cleaner['id']%>');" >SAVE</a>
```

Then finally I was able to access the respective cleaner details by accessing the form name with the cleaner id function parameter.

```
 function contractorEditEmployee(cleaner_id){
    var first_name = document.forms[cleaner_id]["emp-edit-first-name"].value;
    var last_name = document.forms[cleaner_id]["emp-edit-last-name"].value;
```

.
.
.

Hope it helps someone. thanks for all the help.

Comment: Name of the for is duplicate because you are using the loop. form name should be unique here form name is `empEditForm`.
You can create unique name by using a unique number and on click of submit button get name of the form and use it to get values

Comment: @PankajMakwana I was thinking that was the issue too. Can you link me to any source for that?

Comment: Change the name in the form : 
`<form name="empEditForm<%=somecounter%>"  class="toggle-field" style="display: none;" >`

And use class on the submit button and use click event on class name and button should be inside `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Please check below mentioned solution. I hope this will help you.

```
$("#save-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').serialize());
});
```